# Phpmyadmin error in windows 7

Tags: phpmyadmin

I´m trying to install phpmyadmin on windows 7 and when I go to http://localhost/phpmyadmin I just get a red bar saying "phpMyAdmin - Error", and nothing else.
I looked for errors in the apaches logs, but there are none.

I'm running:

- httpd 2.4.20 x64
- mysql 5..49 x64
- php 7.0.5 x64
- phpmyadmin 4.6.0 all-languages

Comment: Can you provide more information? Is there really no more than just `phpMyAdmin - Error`?

Comment: I don't have anymore. How can I get It?

Answer (score 0):

For this situation I used [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/de/index.html). It's a software bundle that delivers and configures you mysql, php/apache and phpmyadmin. 
For an easy start I would suggest you to try XAMPP before you manually install all the packages separately.

Comment: Before I went on the manual install I tried xampp. But after the install I tried to launch apache and mysql in the xampp control panel and it just kept saying launching apache ... and the same with mysql

Comment: If the servers do not start you may are already running these because of an older installation. So the ports are blocked and xampp cant launch them maybe? Try to kill all mysql/apache processes in the task manager and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I revisited the Xampp option and found that xampp already brought an apache and a mysql server with it. In my previous trial I had previously installed apache and mysql.
Apparently they colided
Thanks
Jeraisel